# Why do tag badges show up as "Unearned"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

For those who haven't stumbled on it yet, one of the recent changes SE team made was to add an "unearned" filter to the Badges tab.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=unearned

However, the filter seems to have a small bug, in that it shows Tag Badges among the unearned even for the users who earned at least one of some/each.

Comment: You may have earned one (or a few), but you haven't earned *all of them*.

Comment: @Kevin - is that the official explanation, or you way of tricking me into becoming even MORE of a badge x0re?

Comment: Just trying to goad you on. I'm asking around, we'll see if I dig anything up.

Comment: [Related, on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184959/172958)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.  There's a few ways of looking at tag badges since they represent a group of badges, here's our take on it:

Though there are some you have earned, there are many you have not as well...so they are on both lists.  The only case in which this is a bug is if you earned them *all*...which luckily is a very rare edge case so we don't take the perf hit to check that.

I'll admit it is a bug if it were to happen...and it does, e.g. when the first tag badge for a site is awarded.

Comment: I cannot imagine anyone earning every tag badge that is possible, not even Jon Skeet has done such a feat...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto oh it's possible...if you're the first to earn any tag badge on the site, you're 1/1 :)